# Visual Studio : Replace all references to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings to CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, azure

I'am migrating a .Net application that have all its references to the configuration setting using the normal `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get` method and I want to replace all this references b `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting`. I want to use a regex to replace all the references in the visual studio solution but I am stuck with the RegEx ...

I tried something like that to match the references but that doesn't not work...

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(".?")
```

Can someone help me please^^ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN documentation [Match a string inside quotes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx) :

I used this RegEx :

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get\(((\".+?\")|('.+?'))\)
```

And my replace expression:

```
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting($1)
```

All references updated ^^

**EDIT: Remove direct reference to the configuration manager**

As suggested by Jeff, I've decided to encapsulated the call to the configuration settings and ended with this (I wanted a quick and simple solution):

- Create a class not to have a direct reference to the configuration manager :

  ```
  public static class MyConfigurationManager
  {
      public static string GetSetting(string name)
      {
          return CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(name);
      }
  }
  ```
- So now I can query my settings like that:

  ```
  var mySetting = MyConfigurationManager.GetSetting("mySetting");
  ```
- If I want to go back to the default `ConfigurationManager` (or using another one), I just need to update `MyConfigurationManager` class:

  ```
  public static class MyConfigurationManager
  {
      public static string GetSetting(string name)
      {
          return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(name);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: And this an opportune moment to ditch a direct reference to any particular configuration strategy!